# Plotly R - Showing Potential Y Axis Vaues With No Data

Tags: r, plotly

Good Afternoon,

I am looking for some help as to how to show additional values on my Y axis which are not realized in the data. In the example below, this plot transitions from A to C over three months. I think there are 5 total categories, D and E which are not attained in this particular subset of data. I would still like the Y axis to show D and E as possible values even though the data never realizes those values.

A short working example is provided:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03"), value = c("A","B","C"))

plot_ly(df) %>% add_trace(x = ~date, y= ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines', color = 'orange')
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Some quick Googling suggests plotly doesn't support a `drop=FALSE` argument like ggplot does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you could set the axis range manually via layout but since you have categorical values, we need some hacking.

- Add a dummy trace which has all the categorical values you want to see
- Set the `opacity` to 0 to hide the trace
- Set `showlegend` to `False` so it won't appear in the legend and confuse the user
- Make sure the other trace is shown in the legend, both via `layout` and `showlegend`

[image]

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03"), value = c("A","B","C"))

#this is the dataframe which contains all categorical data
df_all <- data.frame(date = c("2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03"), value = c("A", "D", "E"))

#plot the real data
p <- plot_ly(data = df, 
             x = ~date, 
             y= ~value, 
             type = 'scatter', 
             mode = 'markers+lines', 
             showlegend=T)
#plot the dummy data
p <- add_trace(p, 
               data = df_all, 
               x = ~date, 
               y= ~value, 
               opacity=0, 
               showlegend=F) 
p <- layout(p, showlegend = T)
p
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite novel! Thanks!